# How to change GridView image item resource using OnItemClickListener?

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, ontouchlistener, onitemclicklistener

I am having trouble changing the GridView image item resource when clicked using `OnItemClickListener` and not `OnTouchListener`. The main reason why I want to use `OnItemClickListener`is that I can get the `position` of the item clicked. Once I have the `position`, I use it to determine which image to change. When I press an item I want to change its image resource to `image2`, and when unpressed change it back to `image1`.

This is easy using `OnTouchListener` however I can't get the `position` of the selected GridView item.

Comment: See my answer, and try that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

                int action = me.getActionMasked();  // MotionEvent types such as ACTION_UP, ACTION_DOWN
                float currentXPosition = me.getX();
                float currentYPosition = me.getY();
                int position = gridView.pointToPosition((int) currentXPosition, (int) currentYPosition);

                // Access text in the cell, or the object itself
                String s = (String) gridView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                TextView tv = (TextView) gridView.getChildAt(position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is great, but now my problem is I want to change the ImageView resource but when I used `ImageView iv = (ImageView) gridView.getChildAt(position);` there was a ClassCastException since the `Child` touched was the parent `LinearLayout` not its child `ImageView`. How do I get the child `ImageView` in this instance?